# Make A Pointer Point to What Another Pointer Points To in C

Tags: c, math, memory, pointers, struct

I couldn't really describe my problem in the title, but basically I need some help with pointer arithmetic. Lets say you have a struct like following. Then you get a pointer to after the long in the struct in memory. Lets say the pointer is ***p**. so I would do **p += sizeof(void *)** to get p at the location of the next pointer. Now how do I actually make p point to what next points to rather than just have it point to where the next pointer is in memory?

```
struct freeblock {
  long s; 
  // <--- THE POINTER WOULD BE POINTING HERE
  struct freeblock *prev;
  struct freeblock *next;
}
```

Comment: The most important piece of "help with pointer arithmetic" you should get out of this is that pointer arithmetic in C does not work that way. Pointer arithmetic in C can only be used to skip between array elements. There's no way to use pointer arithmetic to skip from one struct field to another. What you are trying to do is a bizarre hack that has very little (or nothing) to do with C pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Actually AndreyT, with the help of the compiler macro shown by Chad it is possible to skip exactly from the pointer to a field up to the top of the structure, and then down to the field in question. However, it's not for the newbies.  Since the OP is trying to "write a heap" maybe he's ready for that kind of base hackery.

Comment: @Andrey, @Warren: There is a special macro `offsetof()` in the current C standard that allows to apply the sort of pointer arithmetic to structs. I added an answer for that.

Comment: @Alexey Kukanov: That depends on the what the OPO is trying to achieve. Using `offsetof` the "arithmetic" is only possible if you know the specific field you are jumping to. You can't use it to implement the generic "go to the next field operation".

Comment: @Alexey Kukanov: Consider this simple abstract example: you have a variable `unsigned i` and you want to increment it. One way to do it is to do a simple `++i`. Another way to do it is to build a huge ladder of `if`s that will process all possible values of `i` (like `if (i==0) i=1; else if (i==1) i=2; else ...` and so on. The "arithmetic" you propose is exactly like that ladder of `if`s. Meanwhile I suspect the OP wants something like a simple `++i`. It is unavailable for structs.

Comment: @Warren P: Chad's answer is a mess. Plus anything built from `offsetof` will suffer from the problem I mention in my comment above. It is not really a genuine arithmetic, but rather a bunch of branches that handle each specific field independently.

Comment: @Andrey: Yes I agree that the struct should be known for `offsetof` to be useful, and generic jumping to the next field in an arbitrary struct is not possible. However I think that it should be satisfactory to OP since his question seems more of dereferencing than of how to shift to the right address.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void *p; /* points to prev now */
struct freeblock *p1;

p = ((char *)p)+sizeof(struct freeblock *); /* advance p to next */
p1 = *(struct freeblock **)p; /* take whatever is in next */
```

p1 points to the same place as next.

Little explanation - pointers are typed in C. Adding 1 to a pointer means adding sizeof(type) to the actual address, so you need to bring the pointer to a proper type, or to char * if you want manual arithmetics, since sizeof(char) is 1.

Answer (score 2):

This has the potential to be a tricky question. You really don't want to be doing pointer arithmetic in your structs. The reason is [Struct Alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). What happens is if you have a struct like so:

```
struct a{
  char x; //address 0x8
  //potentially 3 bytes lost here:
  int y; //address 0x12
}
```

y is not going to start one byte after x. To preserve alignment, so y starts on, say, an address that's a multiple of 4, there will be some padding bytes added after x.

If you have the address of a struct instance 0x08 and add the size of a char, yielding (0x09) you won't get the start of y 0x12, you'll get some garbage data that's part junk and part y.

In this case you should be OK as the same types are right after one another and you can do something like so:

```
freeblock* p = s.prev;
p += sizeof(p);
freeblock next = *p;
```

You really want to get a pointer to the struct and let the compiler compute the offsets for you.

Comment: the thing i didnt really get across in the question is that i'm not actually mallocing the pointer to the struct, i'm doing it myself simulating the heap. So i already have a large chunk of memory allocated and a pointer to the beginning of that chunk. 
Imagine something like this:
   char * heap [1024];   
   struct freeblock *block = (struct freeblock *)heap;
   block->size = 1024;
   block->prev = 0;
   block->next = 0;
   head = (char*)block + sizeof(long);

Comment: Chads answer uses a little offset() macro and this will work regardless of how the compiler did the struct alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you only know that the current value of `p`, and that it points to a `prev` field of a `struct freeblock` instance. Meanwhile, remember that the "after the long" address may not be the same as the address of `prev` field, e.g. if `sizeof(long)==4` and pointers are aligned at 8 bytes (which is [true for some 64-bit platforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLP64#Specific_C-language_data_models)); see Paul Rubel's answer for explanation.

Now you need to get the value of `next` in the same instance, and dereference it. A standard-compliant solution should probably involve [`offsetof()` macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof):

```
void * p;
...
size_t delta = offsetof(struct freeblock,next)-offsetof(struct freeblock,prev);
p = (void*) *(struct freeblock**)((char*)p+delta);
```

So you first calculate the difference between addresses of `prev` and `next` fields with help of `offsetof()`, then cast `p` to pointer-to-char in order to correctly add the delta and get the address of `next` field, then cast it to pointer-to-pointer-to-freeblock, dereference that address to get the desired value, and finally assign the value to `p` with casting to pointer-to-void (which can be omitted, but I would keep it in production code).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to dereference p, like this:

```
 char *p;
 struct freeblock *x;
// you got the value for p here somehow.
 x = *((struct freeblock **)p);
//  now you can access the fields:
 if (x->next != 0)
 { //...
 }
```

Note that I have chosen to maintain my awareness that the type of x is different than the type of p. You could declare x and p both as void *, but you would have to cast x to '((struct freeblock *)x)' before you could get at the fields.

This is not guaranteed to work, due to compiler alignment issues, etc.  Certainly a terrible way to design your code.

Comment: I think you need to do x = *(struct freeblock **)p;

Comment: I'll try it. You're probably right. The cast from pointer to pointer to struct is required.

Comment: I think Chad's answer is the only reliable one.

Comment: Looks like Chad's answer was replaced by a better one from Alexey.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer should point to a specific type variable, you cannot perform aritmethic actions on `void*`.

But assuming it is some valid data type, then `p++` or `p += 1` will do the job, note that it is dangerous to start casting pointer to different types.

```
struct a{
  long s; 
  int d;// <--- THE p POINTER WOULD BE POINTING HERE
  struct freeblock *prev;
  struct freeblock *next;
}
```

p += 1; // just like d += 1*sizeof(int);

```
struct a{
  long s; 
  int d;
  struct freeblock *prev; // <--- now p points here
  struct freeblock *next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that "p at the location of the `next` pointer" and you want to "make p point to what `next` points to":

I'm going to assume that `p` is a `char*`:

```
p = (char*) *((struct freeblock**) p);
```

A brief explanation:

Since `p` is pointing at `next`, `p` is 'acting' as a pointer to a `struct freeblock*`, or a `struct freeblock**`.  To get the value of what that `struct freeblock**` is pointing to, you simply dereference it (resulting in another pointer, but of the wrong type).  Cast that resulting pointer to the right type for `p` and you're set.